# Stream HDMI over WiFi to Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi, android-wifi

I'm looking to develop an Android app that can view a video stream over Wifi from an HDMI video source. I know I will need some sort of streaming device to stream the HDMI video but am not sure what I will need.

What would the ideal streaming protocol be to view it on Android? Does anyone know of a device that solves this?

EDIT: I've been looking at Teradek's products, and it seems they might accomplish what I want.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I'll delete my answer. Streaming to a Nexus 5 (instead of a TV is not what I was envisioning). But yes, a PC, MythTV, or a Slingbox, should be able to do the trick for you.

Comment: How would those help me? They don't stream something that I can build an Android app that connects to.

Comment: VNC Viewer should be able to view content from a PC. I'm not sure about MythTV, but Slingbox should have its own android client.

Comment: Right but I am developing my own Android app and need to know what the streaming protocol is, RTP,RTSP,RTMP, etc. and how to connect etc. not just download an app and buy a device.